# I'm going to leave a state job a few months after starting. Will this hurt me in the future?

Tags: resignation

First, I'd like to apologize if my questions come off as naive. I graduated 15 months ago and I'm new to having a career.

I've just started a job at a university in Florida, which makes me a state employee. A few weeks after starting, I received an offer from the company I really wanted to work for, but didn't get back to me in time. I really want to take this new offer, but I'm concerned leaving after a short time (one month) will hurt my chances of getting another job working for the state.

So my questions are:

1. Will leaving my current position after such a short time make it harder for me to get another state job (like another university) in the future?
2. Can prospective employers see all the places I've worked (even the ones I've left off my resume) and how long I've worked there through background checks?

Answer (score 0):

> Will leaving my current position after such a short time make it
>   harder for me to get another state job (like another university) in
>   the future?

It could. Employers usually don't like to see someone accept a job then jump to a new job quickly. It makes them worry that you'll do it again (to them).

On the other hand, some employers understand that new graduates don't have enough experience to know what they "really" want and that these kinds of things happen.

> Can prospective employers see all the places I've worked (even the
>   ones I've left off my resume) and how long I've worked there through
>   background checks?

Yes, this could potentially be discovered through a background check.

Answer (score 0):

Moving just the once to another company after such a short time probably wont make much impact. Most employers know some people job hop around once or twice until they find the right role for themselves so I'd take it.